# How would I update the authorization header from a cookie on a graphQL apollo mutation or query

Tags: cookies, graphql, next.js, apollo, faunadb

I have the following _app.js for my NextJS app.

I want to change the authorization header on login via a cookie that will be set, I think I can handle the cookie and login functionaility, but I am stuck on how to get the cookie into the ApolloClient headers autorization. Is there a way to pass in a mutation, the headers with a token from the cookie. Any thoughts here???

I have the cookie working, so I have a logged in token, but I need to change the apolloclient Token to the new one via the cookie, in the _app.js. Not sure how this is done.

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUNA_SECRET}`,
  },
});

console.log(client.link.options.headers);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

UPDATE:I've read something about setting this to pass the cookie int he apollo docs, but I don't quite understand it.

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link,
});
```

UPDATE: So I have made good progress with the above, it allows me to pass via the context in useQuery, like below. Now the only problem is the cookieData loads before the use query or something, because if I pass in a api key it works but the fetched cookie gives me invalid db secret and its the same key.

```
const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

  console.log(cookieData);

  // const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FORMS);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FORMS, {
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + cookieData,
      },
    },
  });
```

Any ideas on this problem would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run some GraphQL queries after some other data is loaded, then I recommend putting the latter queries in a separate React component with the secret as a prop and only loading it once the former data is available.  Or you can use lazy queries.

### separate component

```js
const Form = ({ cookieData }) => {
  useQuery(FORMS, {
    context: {
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + cookieData,
      },
    },
  });

  return /* ... whatever ... */
}

const FormWrapper = () => {
  const { data: cookieData, error: cookieError } = useSWR(
    "/api/cookie",
    fetcher
  );

 return cookieData ? <Form cookieData={ cookieData }/> : ...loading
}
```

I might be missing some nuances with when/how React will mount and unmount the inner component, so I suppose you should be careful with that.

### Manual Execution with `useLazyQuery`

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery